# How I can deserialize a json object without a name and dynamic?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, pojo

I have this JSON:

```
{
    "username": [
        "A user with that username already exists."
    ],
    "ruc": [
        "user with this ruc already exists."
    ],
    "code": [
        "user with this code already exists."
    ],
    "document_number": [
        "user with this document number already exists."
    ]
}
```

The name of the properties will be dynamic and the length of the JSON too.
I'm using GSON tool and I create a POJO but without a name, I cant reference to this, that's, why I received that myError instance, is null.
This is my POJO

```
public class MyError {
    public Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<>();
}
```

And this is my GSON code

```
myError = new Gson().fromJson(response.errorBody().string(), MyError.class);
```

And I want to show a message for every item like this:

```
for (String key : myError.message.keySet()) {
    Utils.showToast(getBaseContext(), "Message: " + myError.message.get(key) + " Field: " + key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this:

```
Map myError = new Gson().fromJson(s, Map.class);
```

Or if you want to use your class json should look like:

`{
  "message": {
    "username": [
      "A user with that username already exists."
    ],
    "ruc": [
      "user with this ruc already exists."
    ],
    "code": [
      "user with this code already exists."
    ],
    "document_number": [
      "user with this document number already exists."
    ]
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Gson and java native JsonParser.